Recommendations for Open Access Journals in Operations Research with Quick Review Times and Low Fees
I'm currently working on a research paper in the field of operations research (specifically, My proposal is a hybrid learning heuristic for a variant of the vehicle routing problem) and am looking for recommendations on suitable journals to submit my work. Specifically, I am interested in:

Open Access Journals: Journals that provide open access to published papers to ensure wide dissemination of research findings.

Quick Review Times: Journals known for their relatively fast peer review process, ideally within a few months.

Low Publication Fees: Journals that charge lower article processing charges (APCs) compared to typical high-fee journals.


Could anyone suggest some journals that meet these criteria?
Additionally, any personal experiences with the submission process, review times, and overall satisfaction with the journal would be useful.

What method(s) and/or application(s)?   OR is a big field and there are many open-access journals that cater to specific application areas.  More details would help the community provide better answers.

For wide dissemination and no fee, why not arxiv? There's no review, but... that doesn't sound like a priority of yours.
